# How to create Handler

Tags: .net, c++, handler

Add next changes:

```
Emily::oSeMac^ Terminal;
    Emily::AsyncSocketController^ _socketManager;
    delegate void DataArrival(String^, array<unsigned char, 1>^, System::Net::IPEndPoint^);

    void _socketManager_onDataArrival(String^ SocketID, array<unsigned char, 1>^ SocketData, System::Net::IPEndPoint^ RemoteIP)
    {
        System::Object^ retData = Terminal->WhoCame (SocketID, SocketData, RemoteIP, _socketManager, 0); 
    }
    Form1(void)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _socketManager = gcnew Emily::AsyncSocketController(2000);
        _socketManager->onDataArrival += gcnew DataArrival(this, &AC_WebPassManager::Form1::_socketManager_onDataArrival);
        _socketManager->Start();
        Terminal = gcnew Emily::oSeMac();
    }
```

Error error C2664: 'Emily::AsyncSocketController::onDataArrival::add' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'AC_WebPassManager::Form1::DataArrival ^' to 'Emily::AsyncSocketController::onDataArrivalEventHandler ^'
1>        No user-defined-conversion operator available, or
1>        Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast
1>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
_socketManager->onDataArrival += gcnew DataArrival(this,
    &Test::Form1::_socketManager_onDataArrival_);
```

DataArrival is delegate:

```
public delegate DataArrival(String^, array<unsigned char, 1>^, System::Net::IPEndPoint^);
```

Possibly it is already defined somewhere, with other name - look this delegate definition in Emily namespace.

Comment: OK, I change code

Emily::oSeMac^ Terminal;
Emily::AsyncSocketController^ _socketManager;
public: delegate DataArrival(String^, array<unsigned char, 1>^, System::Net::IPEndPoint^);
void _socketManager_onDataArrival(String^ SocketID, array<unsigned char, 1>^ SocketData, System::Net::IPEndPoint^ RemoteIP)
  {
System::Object^ retData = Terminal->WhoCame (SocketID, SocketData, RemoteIP, _socketManager, 0); 
  }

Comment: Form1(void)
  {
   InitializeComponent();
   _socketManager = gcnew Emily::AsyncSocketController(2000);
   _socketManager->onDataArrival += gcnew DataArrival(this, &AC_WebPassManager::Form1::_socketManager_onDataArrival);
   _socketManager->Start();
   Terminal = gcnew Emily::oSeMac();
  }

Comment: Errors
1>d:\projects\ac_webpassmanager\ac_webpassmanager\Form1.h(36) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'DataArrival'
1>d:\projects\ac_webpassmanager\ac_webpassmanager\Form1.h(36) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>d:\projects\ac_webpassmanager\ac_webpassmanager\Form1.h(36) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>d:\projects\ac_webpassmanager\ac_webpassmanager\Form1.h(36) :

Comment: warning C4183: 'DataArrival': missing return type; assumed to be a member function returning 'int'
1>d:\projects\ac_webpassmanager\ac_webpassmanager\Form1.h(46) : error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'DataArrival'

Comment: Your comments are unreadable, please edit original question and describe the problem there.

Comment: Regarding DataArrival delegate: it must be already defined somewhere, AsyncSocketController::onDataArrival event has this type. Find this delegate in the library you are using, and use actual delegate name instead of DataArrival.

Comment: No, It must be my delegate, because I must add my code in this delegate. For exanple, when I call some function from library than when library get all data from controller then I must parse this data. I have demo code but on VB .NET

Comment: Emily::AsyncSocketController::onDataArrivalEventHandler is required delegate type. Remove DataArrival definition and write:

_socketManager->onDataArrival += gcnew Emily::AsyncSocketController::onDataArrivalEventHandler(this,
    &Test::Form1::_socketManager_onDataArrival_);

Comment: Fine. Since you are new user, possibly you don't know that accepting the answer is done by clicking the "v" button near the answer. This is not intuitive, I found this only after asking my first 10 questions in this forum :)